# Two class in a Single File

Tags: java

I'm preparing the OCA Java 8 Certified Exam.

In the book says:

> If do you have a public class, it needs to match the filename. public
>   class animal2 would not compile in a file name Animal.java. The sample
>   code is:

```
public class Animal{
private String name;
}
class Animal2{

}
```

But, if I create a Java file called "Animal.java", I put the code inside and compile it, the compiler generates two java class, "animal.class" and "animal2.class".

Is the study guide wrong?

Comment: `Animal2` is not a public class.

Comment: "Java provides a default specifier which is used when no access modifier is present. Any class, field, method or constructor that has no declared access modifier is accessible only by classes in the same package. The default modifier is not used for fields and methods within an interface". http://www.wideskills.com/java-tutorial/introduction-to-java-access-modifiers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the book is saying that if a file is named Animal the public class must also be called Animal, otherwise, there is an error.

`class Animal2` isn´t public that's why it compiles fine.

What you can do is have a public class within a public class:

```
public class Animal{

    public class Animal2{
        ...
    }

    ...

}
```

This is not possible:

```
public class Animal{
      ....
}

public class Animal2{
      ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, ok.

I understand now, the book has confusing me.

This compiles and generates two Class (One public class Animal, and one protected class animal2):

```
public class Animal{
private String name;
}
class Animal2{

}
```

This NOT compile:

```
public class Animal{
private String name;
}
public class Animal2{

}
```

Comment: this doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: Yes, you only can have a public class in a java file, and the name of the public class has to match with the java file name.